# Cocos2D scene is not full screen in iOS6

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have no problems with iOS5 and 5.1. Scene is loading without problems.. 
[image]

However iOS6 gives me a small problem.. Scene is not full screen unlike the image above..

[image]

How can I fix this issue? Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

Looks like an anchorpoint issue rather than a fullscreen issue.

Assuming a position of (0,0) for both - your top image has an anchorpoint of (0,0), while the bottom one is (0.5, 0.5).

Though more information is needed about your code.

**EDIT:** With the code you listed, it looks like they hard-coded the SCREEN_CENTER define as:

```
#define SCREEN_CENTER       CGPointMake(240, 160)
```

I would replace SCREEN_CENTER with:

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CGPoint point = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
```

Comment: What part of the code do you need to see? I am using the FruitAssasin example project.. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1-yARGKhXU`